# Framework7 stopPropagation solution

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

http://jsfiddle.net/p168uLv2/3/

Here you see my jsFiddle accompanied by my problem. I have a button in a click handler and when I press the button the click also registered on the div where the button is part of. With jQuery you can stopPropagaton so that does't happen, but on framework7 it doesn't work.

```
<div data-link="level1" class="limodeknop">
     <div class="overlay"></div>
     <div class="modeknop">
          <div class="titel">
             <lrmodenaam>Level 1</lrmodenaam>
             <lrsubmode>Tutorial</lrsubmode>
          </div>
          <div class="knoppenbalk displaynone">
           <div data-link="solo" class="solo btn">Solo</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the Javascript:

```
var $$ = Dom7;

$$(document).on('click',"[data-link=level1]", function(){
    console.log("li clicked");

    $$(this).find(".knoppenbalk").toggleClass("displaynone");

});

$$(document).on('click',"[data-link=solo]", function(e){
    console.log("solo BUTTON clicked");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is in Framework7's realization of event binding. Both callbacks fires when 'click' event reaches root document's node. So 'stopPropagation' on this step is useless.

You can use 'stopImmediatePropagation', but you have to arrange click handlers in the right order in this case. Be careful, 'stopImmediatePropagation' will prevent all another handlers, binded to the element, so do not use 'document' as a target.

Also it is possible to use 'stopPropagation' on the bubble step to reach same effect.

```
var $$ = Dom7;
$$('.limodeknop')
  .on('click', "[data-link=solo]", function (e) {
    console.log("solo BUTTON clicked");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$$('.limodeknop')
  .on('click', "[data-link=level1]", function () {
    console.log("li clicked");
    $$(this)
  .find(".knoppenbalk")
  .toggleClass("displaynone");
});
```

My [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Floky87/pen/ZQEabG?editors=001) example.

Comment: Thank you :) This solved my issue with event propagation.